# Not Getting updated data in custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a method available in another controller and it is returning current report data and when ever i change the report i am not getting new data in my directive and it is still showing old data and if i refresh the browser it is giving new data.

```
angular.controller("sample", ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
     $scope.getNewsData = function(){
        var data = {name: XYZ}
        return data;
     }
}])
```

I am accessing above controller method inside my directive using isolate scope(&) and my question is how to get new data with out refreshing the browser.

```
angular.directive('myDir',function(){
     return {
      restrict:'A',
      scope:{
           getNewsData :&getnew;
       },
      controller:'myDirController',
      templateUrl: 'news.html',
      link:function(scope, $elm, attr){           
          var obj = scope.getNewsData 
      } 
   }
});
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: is this code working? it is having multiple syntax errors

Comment: Could you please add a plunker?

Comment: this is just sample code

Comment: please post plunker!, do you use getNewsData in your element attribute? and call the function to get the result object `var obj = scope.getNewsData(); `

Comment: It is just sample code of above question...I can create  plunker but the code is very big and also i am getting data from server ...

Comment: yes i am using in my element as a attribute

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on`?

in directive you will add a listener everytime you change the data.

```
app.directive('myDir',function(){
  return {
      scope:{
           getNewsData :"&"
       },
      link:function(scope, $elm, attr){           
        var obj = scope.getNewsData(); 
        var cleanup = scope.$on('changeValue', function() {
          console.log(scope.getNewsData());
          obj = scope.getNewsData();
        })

       //make sure to destroy to avoid memory leaks
        scope.$on('$destroy', cleanup);
      } 
   }
});
```

to the method that change the value you must add `$rootScope.$broadcast`

```
app.controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,MainService) {
  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    MainService.setter("xyz");
    $rootScope.$broadcast('changeValue');
  }
});
```

I just add factory for simple passing of data(setter/getter)

```
app.factory('MainService', function() {
  var data;
  return {
    getter: function() {
      return data;
    },
    setter: function(value) {
      data = value;
    }
  }

})
```

For working demo click  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yHpu5ExKNjFa0tgsvWEn?p=preview)

Comment: In "OtherCtrl" you are using $broadcast  and later  you are using $on for getting that data.
In my  development code i am just returning that data 
Is there any other way to get that updated data without using $broadcast and $on???

Comment: If i use $broadcast and $on it leads to performance issues that's why i am not using ...

Comment: try to use $interval? im not sure for using it. I think it is more expensive to use. $interval(function() {
          var obj = scope.getNewsData();   
          console.log(obj);
        }, 1000)